# Sorted values in Object Array using a variable in function

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

I am trying to create a function where it takes in the key of the object needed to sort the values(in this case 'kills'). I tried using `dynamicSort` stated in [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value), but I'm just getting the list returned. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong here?

```js
const list = [
    {
        name: 'compass',
        kills: 35,
        assists: 312
    },
    {
        name: 'another one',
        kills: 52,
        assists: 32
    },
    {
        name: 'another anothe one',
        kills: 12,
        assists: 30
    }
];

const sortByType = (property) => {
  return function (a, b) {
    let result;
    if (a[property] < b[property]) {
      result = -1;
    }
    if (a[property] > b[property]) {
      result = 1;
    }
    else {
      result = 0;
    }
    return result;
  };
}

let newList = list.sort(sortByType('kills'));
console.log(newList);
```

EDITED: updated how the code is being used.

Comment: Show how you're using it.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Side note that the entire contents of your method could be reduced to `return a[property] - b[property]`

Comment: @Taplar That only works for numeric data, not strings.

Comment: Sure, but given what their method is currently doing, it would be the same.

Comment: @Taplar It looks like it should work correctly for the `name` property.

Comment: Your `if` `if` `else` block should be an `if` `else if` `else` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you could just simply sort the array using the property in the sort function.

Ascending order `a[property] - b[property]`
Descending order `b[property] - a[property]`

the sort by name is converting all the names into an array sorting them and then looping through to have it sorted. This runs in `n^2` so it worth looking into optimizations, but this will get you across the finish line.

NOTE: this function will not work is `name` is `undefined`.

```js
const list = [
    {
        name: 'compass',
        kills: 35,
        assists: 312
    },
    {
        name: 'another one',
        kills: 52,
        assists: 32
    },
    {
        name: 'another anothe one',
        kills: 12,
        assists: 30
    }
]


const sortByString = () => {
    const strings = list.map(prop => prop.name).sort();
    let sorted = [];
    for(const idx in strings){
        let currString = strings[idx];
        for(const objIdx in list){
            console.log(currString, list[objIdx].name)
            if(list[objIdx].name === currString){
                sorted.push(list[objIdx]);
            }
        }
    }
    return sorted;
}
const dynamicSortByType = (property) => {
    return typeof list[0][property] === 'string' ? 
    sortByString() : list.sort((a,b) => a[property] - b[property])
}
console.log(dynamicSortByType('name'))
```

Comment: The method in the question should work to sort by strings.

Comment: So one thing I added the string sort. It is running in n^2 so with really large objects it might be slow. It worth looking into optimizing. Just putting strings into an array to sort was the best option I could think of

Answer (score 1):

#### Short answer:

You're just missing the word `else`.

#### Long answer:

You have a block that looks like

```
if () {
}
if () {
}
else {
}
```

that should look like:

```
if () {
}
else if () {
}
else {
}
```

**Notice** the addition of the `else` before the second `if`.  Without it, the second if-else will run and the final else will supersede the setting made by the truthy case of the first `if`.

For example, any time `if (a[property] < b[property]) {`, it will actually fall through the second `if`'s `else` and result in setting `result = 0`.

Here is your snippet with the tiny repair made:

```js
const list = [
    {
        name: 'compass',
        kills: 35,
        assists: 312
    },
    {
        name: 'another one',
        kills: 52,
        assists: 32
    },
    {
        name: 'another anothe one',
        kills: 12,
        assists: 30
    }
];

const sortByType = (property) => {
  return function (a, b) {
    let result;
    if (a[property] < b[property]) {
      result = -1;
    }
    else if (a[property] > b[property]) {  /* FIXED:  added `else` on this line */
      result = 1;
    }
    else {
      result = 0;
    }
    return result;
  };
}

let newList = list.sort(sortByType('kills'));
console.log(newList);
```